# Share VPC among stacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-vpc

I am writing the code like this below

```
export interface MyEc2StackProps extends StackProps {
}
export class MyEc2Stack extends Stack {  
  public readonly vpc: ec2.Vpc;
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: MyEc2StackProps) {
    const vpc = ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(this, "myvpc", {
      isDefault: true,
    });
    this.vpc = vpc; #  this can't be compiled
```

I want to get the vpc and export vpc to use in other stacks.

However this shows the error, `IVpc has no property from Vpc....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch your member type from `ec2.Vpc` to `ec2.IVpc`. You need to do that because `ec2.Vpc.fromLookup` returns `ec2.IVpc`. It's not creating a real VPC, but looking one up. Not all operations will be available because it's not being created in your code. But you should be able to use `IVpc` for most things.

Comment: I understood I shoud use ec2.IVpc instead of ec2.Vpc for sharing.